# The [if-else] tag should be synonym of [if-statement], [if-then-else], [if-else-statement]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I proposed that [if-else](/questions/tagged/if-else) become an [if-statement synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/if-statement/synonyms) nearly two months ago. It is clearly justified in becoming a synonym considering that [if-else-statement](/questions/tagged/if-else-statement) and [if-then-else](/questions/tagged/if-then-else) are synonyms of [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement) already.

[if-else](/questions/tagged/if-else) has had 26 more questions tagged in it since I proposed the synonym, so I am posting this as a 'question' here because I think we are doing the site a disservice by not synonymizing them sooner. Please [vote for or against the synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/if-statement/synonyms). And while you're there, perhaps you should [vote on all other proposed synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) considering synonym suggestions apparently get little attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed: [if-else](/questions/tagged/if-else) --> [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement)